# command prompt cant find .NET v 4.6.2

Tags: .net, msbuild, command-prompt

I am on win10 using command prompt and need to run a Visual Studio project using .net version 4.6.2.

In command prompt if I run `dotnet --version` I see:

```
C:\Users\320178017>dotnet --version
3.1.202
```

Running `dotnet --list-sdks` I see:

```
C:\Users\320178017>dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Running `dotnet --list-runtimes` I see:

```
C:\Users\320178017>dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

I already tried downloading and installing version 4.6.2 from this source:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net462

I get a popup window saying ".NET Framework 4.6.2 or a later update is already installed on this computer"

if it is already installed why dont i see version 4.6.2 in any of my command prompt terminal commands, and is there any way I can switch to using this version of .net ?

Answer (score 0):

'.Net Framework' is the older Windows-only implementation of .Net and the dotnet CLI doesn't support .Net Framework, e.g. `dotnet build` will not work for a .Net Framework project.

The dotnet CLI supports the '.Net Core' implementation which at version 5 was renamed to just '.Net'. The runtimes and sdks listed by the dotnet command are all .Net Core or .Net.

Yes it can be confusing. See [.NET implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/implementations) for some help.

Note that .Net Core 3.x was followed by .Net 5. Anything 4.x is .Net Framework.

You can build your .NET Framework 4.6.2 project at the command line with MSBuild, e.g.:

```
msbuild app.sln
```

The dotnet tool has an msbuild command that just runs msbuild, so something like the following should also work:

```
dotnet msbuild app.sln
```